# linq statuses must return distinct

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a DB table that looks similar to this.

**ID** | **Status** | **Type**

[image]

etc...etc

I am using linq to try and discern distinct Statuses from this collection like so

```
results = ctx.Status.Distinct(new StatusComparer()).ToList();
```

but this returns all statuses, I used the following [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) to construct the Comparer below, I found that suggestion in another StackOverflow [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values?rq=1)

```
    public class StatusComparer : IEqualityComparer<Status>
{
    public bool Equals(Status x, Status y)
    {
        // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the status' properties are equal. 
        return x.StatusDescription == y.StatusDescription && x.Type == y.Type && x.StatusID == y.StatusID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Status status)
    {
        // Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        var hashStatusId = status.StatusID.GetHashCode();

        // Get hash code for the Code field. 
        var hashStatusDescription = status.StatusDescription.GetHashCode();

        var hashStatusType = status.Type.GetHashCode();

        // Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashStatusId ^ hashStatusDescription ^ hashStatusType;
    }
}
}
```

My problem is as follows early on we had a system that worked fine, so well in fact they wanted another system using the same Database so we plumbed it in. The search has an advanced options with several filters one of them being Status but as you can see from the above (loose) DB structure statuses have different types but similar text. I need to be able to select via Linq the whole status by the distinct text. all help would be greatly appreciated.

have also tried

```
results = (from s in context.Status group s by s.StatusDescription into g select        g.First()).ToList();
```

this also failed with a System.NotSupportedException

Comment: I re-tagged this as `c#` for you.  It's definitely not `c`.

Comment: thank you less haste more speed ;)

Comment: have tried results = (from s in context.Status group s by s.StatusDescription into g select g.First()).ToList(); this also fails

Answer (score 2):

To select all distinct statuses:

```
ctx.Status.Select(s => new { s.StatusDescription, s.Type }).Distinct();
```

Comment: I think the combination of StatusDescription and StatusType is needed to determine the value.

Comment: when I try this I do not get Status as an option from intellisense but I tried anyway and this does not compile, can you explain what you were trying to demonstrate to me?

Comment: I'm assuming here that `ctx.Status` is your `IQueryable`. That's what it looks like in the OP. The `Select` and `Distinct` are the LINQ method calls.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm still getting back all statuses :(

Comment: Why don't you post the data you're getting and the data you expect to get?