# Find Distinct elements from a List C#

Tags: c#, list, distinct-values

I have a class say named `Product`

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public int ProductId{ get; set; }

}
```

I have a list of Products, with same `Name`, but different `ProductId`.

I want to get distinct products from the list on `product.Name`

i.e. if the list is

```
var fullproductList = {
        Name: product,
        ProductId: 1
    }, {
        Name: product,
        ProductId: 2
    }, {
        Name: product,
        ProductId: 3
    };
```

I want any one the above product.

I want to achieve this without looping like this:

```
List<Product> distinctProducts= new List<Product>();

var distictproductName=fullSubjectList.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var item in distictproductName)
{
    distinctProducts.Add(fullproductList.Where(x=>x.Name==item).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using [`MoreLinq`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) you can use `Distinct` with lambda:

```
fullSubjectList.DistinctBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Neat! Am going to add MoreLinq to my project today!

Comment: You could also check the source code of that particular method: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Comment: @gdoron Several fields in DistinctBy:  res = res.DistinctBy(i => i.Name).DistinctBy(i => i.ProductId).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Use linq with a group by on name. That will give you the distinct.
Look at this answer for a few ideas : [LINQ: Distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values)

Comment: +1. Note that `DistinctBy` from `MoreLinq` is going to be a bit more efficient though. See the comments in the source from that link.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of that library.