# union in two linq statements and remove the duplicate

Tags: c#, linq

I have been searching for a while in the internet yet cant find what i really needed. My problem is that I have two linq statements which I am planning to have them in UNION so that they'll be mergen into 1 single set of list but I want to removed those duplicate values. To be specific here is the a scenario:

```
query 1 = "this is a test","Yes", "This is a remark"
          "this is a test2","No", "This is the second remark"

query 2 = "this is a test","",""
          "this is a test2","",""
          "this is a test3","",""
          "this is a test4","",""
```

now what I want to happen is something like this:

```
          "this is a test","Yes", "This is a remark"
          "this is a test2","No", "This is the second remark",
          "this is a test3","",""
          "this is a test4","",""
```

How can I do this in LINQ?thanks in advance!

Comment: You tried .Distinct()?

Comment: Yes sir.. tried it but no effect..

Comment: what will be the return from the query?

Comment: "this is a test","Yes", "This is a remark"
          "this is a test2","No", "This is the second remark",
          "this is a test3","",""
          "this is a test4","",""

this is what im expecting sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following query:

```
var result = from item in query2
             let match = query1.SingleOrDefault (e => e[0] == item[0])
             select match ?? item;
```

This will iterate over `query2`, and for each item it uses `SingleOrDefault` to find the item in `query1` where the first elements of the items match, or `null`. Then the `select` yields either the item called match from `query1`, if it is not `null`, or the current item of `query2`.

---

Another, probably faster approach is to create an appropriate `IEqualityComparer` and using `Union`, like this:

```
class FirstElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    //TODO error checking
    public bool Equals(string[] a, string[] b)
    {       
        return a[0].Equals(b[0]);
    }

    public Int32 GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        return obj[0].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    string[][] query1 = {new [] {"this is a test","Yes", "This is a remark"},
                         new [] {"this is a test2","No", "This is the second remark"}};

    string[][] query2 = {new [] {"this is a test","",""},
                         new [] {"this is a test2","",""},
                         new [] {"this is a test3","",""},
                         new [] {"this is a test4","",""}};

    query1.Union(query2, new FirstElementComparer()).Dump();                         
}
```

The `EqualityComparer` is used by `Union` to compare the elements in `query1` with the elements in `query2`. It does so by just comparing the first item in each array.

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: HI sir!this has solved the problem.. can you explain this to me sir??? Thanks a lot!im new to linq

Comment: @VincentClyde I added some explanations.

Comment: Won't work when there are items in query1 not present in query2.

Comment: @Serge True for the first solution, but OP said that this is ever the case (in a deleted comment).

Comment: @Dominic, what's "Dump"? Is it part of System.Linq?

Comment: @Serge No, it's an extension method provided by [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net) to print any object, as you see in the image. If you don't know linqpad, you really should give it a try :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this...

```
query1.Union(query2).GroupBy(q => q[0]).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());
```

(not tested)

Comment: Should be `Select` instead of `SelectMany`, otherwise, this should work. Also you could use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, since each group will have at least one element, so using the `...OrDefault` variant is pointless. Since the elements of the collections won't match using the `Default`-comparer, `Union` is equivalent to `Concat` here, probably a (very little bit) slower.

Comment: Yes I just noticed about SelectMany. As for FirstOrDefault, you're perfectly right but it's kind of an habit for me to use it. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try using .Distinct().  See the link below for more info:

[LINQ: Distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values)