# Generic list with unique items

Tags: vb.net, generic-list

I have the class like:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Item As String
    Public StorageLocation As String
    Public NewQuantity As Double
    Sub New(item As String, location As String, quantity As Double)
        Me.Item = item
        Me.Location = location
        Me.NewQuantity = quantity
    End Sub
End Class
```

and I want to have a generic list in which I could select unique objects with unique sets of Item & Location. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: Distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values)

Comment: Use HashSet(Of Foo).  Be sure to override GetHashCode() on Foo.