# Select Distinct rows using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The data is as follow

```
ID Title        Category About           Link        CategoryID
1  The Matrix   Sci-Fi   Text goes here  http://...  1 
2  The Simpsons Cartoon  Text goes here  http://...  2
3  Avengers     Action   Text goes here  http://...  3
4  The Matrix   Sci-Fi   Text goes here  http://...  1
5  The One      Sci-Fi   Text goes here  http://...  1
6  The Hobbit   Sci-Fi   Text goes here  http://...  1
```

I have a checkbox list containing the categories. The problem is if the user selects 'Action' and 'Sci-Fi' as category to display The Matrix will be displayed twice.

This is my try for getting unique rows in SQL Query.

```
select distinct title, about, link from mytable
inner join tableCategories on categoryID = tableCategoriesID
group by title, about, link
```

Using the LINQ,

```
(from table in movieTables
join x in categoryIDList
on categoryID equals x
slect table).Distinct()
```

Note that the categories are in a separate table linked by the categoryID.
Need help displaying unique or distinct rows in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can happily select your result into a list of whatever you want:

```
var v = from entry in tables
        where matching_logic_here
        select new {id = some_id, val=some_value};
```

and then you can run your distinct on that list (well, a `ToList()` on the above will make it one), based on your needs.

The following should illustrate what i mean (just paste into linqpad. if you're using VS, get rid of the `.Dump()`:

```
void Main()
{
    var input  = new List<mock_entry> {
        new mock_entry {id = 1, name="The Matrix", cat= "Sci-Fi"},
        new mock_entry {id = 2, name="The Simpsons" ,cat= "Cartoon"},
        new mock_entry {id = 3, name="Avengers" ,cat= "Action"},
        new mock_entry {id = 4, name="The Matrix", cat= "Sci-Fi"},
        new mock_entry {id = 5, name="The One" ,cat= "Sci-Fi"},
        new mock_entry {id = 6, name="The Hobbit",cat= "Sci-Fi"},
    };

    var v = input.Where(e=>e.cat == "Action" || e.cat =="Sci-Fi")
                .Dump()
                .Select(e => new {n = e.name, c =e.cat})
                .Dump()
    ;

    var d = v.Distinct()
            .Dump()
    ;
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public struct mock_entry {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string cat {get;set;}
}
```

Another option would be to use `DistinctBy` from **more linq** as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values)

**Edit:**

Even simpler, you can use `GroupBy`, and just select the first entry (you'll lose the id though, but up to you).
Here's an example that will work with the above:

```
var v = input.GroupBy (i => i.name)
   .Select(e => e.First ())
   .Dump()
   .Where(e=>e.cat == "Action" || e.cat =="Sci-Fi")
   .Dump()
;
```

will yield:

> 1 The Matrix Sci-Fi
>   3 Avengers Action
>   5 The One Sci-Fi
>   6 The Hobbit Sci-Fi