# Find distinct values from a list of object by one field only

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

How to select distinct values from a list of objects?
I want to get only a list of specific field but not a list of the whole object.

For example the collection to be queried:

```
name   year
Item1  2009
Item2  2009
Item3  2010
Item4  2010
Item5  2011
Item6  2011
```

and from that I want to return distinct years to get the below result collection

```
2009
2010
2011
2012
```

I tried

```
distinctyears = myCollection.GroupBy(x => x.year).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

but that will return a collection of the whole object instead of only the year values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: Distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
distinctyears = myCollection.Select(x => x.year).Distinct()
```

Will return you an `IEnumerable<int>` (or whatever type year is)

no need to do a grouping - all you want is the year in the result, so just grab that.