# Select distinct values from SelectListItem

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `List<SelectListItem>` that I build from a List that contains videos so I can create a dropdown in the view but I only want to select the unique values, I have tried to select distinct:

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var video in VidModel)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = video.Name, Value = video.showName, Selected = false });
        }          
     ViewBag.showName = items.Distinct();
```

But this returns all the values

Comment: Do any of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values) help?

Comment: I think that's for Linq queries and I'm trying to use a SelectListItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `group by` on your items.

```
var uniqueItems= items.GroupBy(s=>s.Value,i=> i, (k ,item) => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = item.First().Text,
    Value=k,
    Selected = item.First().Selected

}).ToList();
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do . But I think instead of doing this on the `SelectListItem` collection ,you should be doing on the data you use to build the `SelectListItem` collection (`VidModel` ?).