# distinct values in linq

Tags: html, linq

I try linq query

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="regiondrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="regiondrop_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I try to show distinct values in drop-down 
on page load. 
I try this query to get values

```
T1 tea = new T1();
var list1 = tea.t1.ToList();
var list = (from ta in list1
orderby ta.Region
select new { ta.Region,ta.RegionID }).Distinct().ToList();
```

but this shows all same values where as i want distinct values

**update**

in my scenario data is

```
RID  Region 
1   Paris   
2   Canada  
3   UK  
4   Paris   
5   Canada 
6   London
```

so in this Canada and Paris 2 times so i want this 1 time in drop-down

any solution?

Comment: What type is `Region`? You're also not showing that you are using `list` as datasource for the `DropDownList`.

Comment: ...Because they have different id's (?)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
var list1 = tea.t1
            .GroupBy(i => i.Region)
            .Select(i => new 
            {
                RegionID = i.Min(t => t.RegionID) // Or Max what you want
                Region = i.Key,                 
            })
            .OrderBy(i => i.Region).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get values distinct by a property -like Region- you can use GroupBy function.

```
T1 tea = new T1();
var list1 = tea.t1.ToList();
var list = (from ta in list1
        orderby ta.Region
        select new { ta.Region, ta.RegionID })
        .GroupBy(g=>g.Region)
        .Select(g=>g.First())
        .ToList();
```

For an extension method : [LINQ: Distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values?rq=1)

Comment: in my scenario.. data is ..                                                                     `RID     Region 
1 Paris 
2 Canda 
3 UK 
4 Paris 
5 Canda
6       London `                                                                                                     now in this canada and paris  appear 2 times so i want this 1 time in dropdown

Comment: this solution not work . when i try this data displayed in dropdown multiple times ...check update please

Comment: Then group by `Region` instead `RegionId`. I edited sample code.