# Conditions on foreach loop using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, Records> mylist;`

I would like to loop in the list foreach different key value. 
Something like

```
foreach(var item in myList.select(/\*query the disctinct values of key here ?*/)
```

is it possible ? How ?

Comment: You can probably get a good footing by looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values), for starters..

Comment: I'll check it, thanks

Comment: If you have a list of pairs that has duplicate keys, how will you determine which value to use for a key that has multiple values tied to it? Ex: `key: 1, value: "hello"`; `key: 1, value: "world"`. How do you pick between "hello" and "world" since they have the same key?

Comment: I may have poorly explain my needs. I will reuse your comment exemple to help me. I need something like serialize/display/process together all elements with key = 1, then serialize/display/process together all element with key = 2, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
foreach(var item in myList.Select(x => x.Key).Distinct())
{
    //Your Logic
}
```

`myList.Select(x => x.Key).Distinct()` would give you distinct Keys and `foreach` will loop over them.

Comment: That seems exactly what i need. I have an error though, `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,Records>>' 
`

Comment: Will it loop every element in myList ? Or just once per distinct key ?

Comment: `myList.Select(x => x.Key)` will have all keys, irrespective of occurrence. `Distinct` will do the distinct.