# How to Select distinct row in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6, entity

I am using following command in sql server to get data:

```
Select distinct ConstituentGroupNameId,UserId,CreatedTime  from dbo.ConstituentRecords
```

But I am unable to implement it through entity framework.I am tring to get unique ConstituentGroupNameId and other field as well.

Comment: i think this answers your question- https://stackoverflow.com/a/998091/7671991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `groupby` in Linq query. It can reach same result like T-SQL's `distinct` operate.

---

Group fields you want to distinct first, you can get the groups you create. Then you select the first of items in groups.

Finally, You get the distinct rows you filter.

Lambda expression :

```
var boo = ConstituentRecords
.GroupBy(o => new { o.ConstituentGroupNameId, o.UserId, o.CreatedTime } )
.Select(g=>g.First())
.ToList();
```

or

query expression  :

```
var boo = (from v in ConstituentRecords
           group v by new { v.ConstituentGroupNameId, v.UserId, v.CreatedTime } into g
           select g.First()).ToList();
```